# Move woocommerce product short description and product data field in right side column of the product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want to show woocommerce product short description and product data in rightside column of the product page. By default all woocommerce product page show product title, product pricing and short description on the top right corner of the page beside image placeholder but I want to move this fields to right side column and make this column sticky. Right now I have added short description and price manually
[here is the ref image of product  page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eSFs.png)

I tried to call this class="woocommerce-product-details__short-description" in column

i.e `<div class="woocommerce-product-details__short-description">`

but its is only working for buttons not for short descriptions and price

Comment: Can you please share link of your single product page (better if you roll back the modification you have made)

Comment: here is the link - https://www.bots4ip.com/product/inspat-proofreading-patent-claims/

Comment: Thank you. I checked and the right side looks sticky already

Comment: yes but how can I add product short description in right column

Comment: There is a short text under the "10 Credits" on your page. Isn't it short description? Is it hard coded text there?

Comment: No it is not hard.  Right now i have added it manually but now I want to pick it from  "woocommerce-product-details__short-description" because it is creating many issues like i have to assign credits manually (10 credit ). it is not picking up credits/price form product data field that usually other woo commerce product does

Comment: I submitted my answer. You can find the shortcode for `short description` and php code for `product price`. I can convert the php code for price to a shortcode as well if you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the **short description** content using the custom shortcode code below.

```
add_shortcode( 'product_short_description', 'display_product_short_description' );
function display_product_short_description( $atts ){
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => get_the_id(),
    ), $atts, 'product_short_description' );

    global $product;

    if ( ! is_a( $product, 'WC_Product') )
        $product = wc_get_product($atts['id']);

    return $product->get_short_description();
}
```

It can be used directly by using shortcode

`[product_short_description]`

or by calling it in product page

`echo do_shortcode( "[product_short_description]" );`

To get the **product price** you can use the following code in your product page

```
<?php $price = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_price', true ); ?>
<p><?php echo wc_price( $price ); ?></p>
```

Comment: [product_short_description] this short code is not working. I have paste this custom short code in snippets and use this short code in product page right column. but it not working

Comment: @TwinklePandagre I tested the shortcode and it works properly. Make sure you are using the shortcode in a real product page. In other pages, you need to add product id to the shortcode. Example: `[product_short_description id='55']`